# How to root my Karbonn A51+ Mobile?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, root-access, stock-rom, karbonn-a51+

My phone is not rooted. I'm using a Karbonn A51+ Mobile.

It's running the Stock ROM:  Android 4.4.2 "KitKat".

I have tried some apps to make it rooted like *Kingo, Iroot, Framaroot* and a tool like *[SRS Root Tool](http://srs-root.com/)*

Screenshot; I'm getting this error while trying with Framaroot:

<sub>(Click for larger variant)</sub>

[image: IMG: Framaroot Error #9]

Please do help me to root my phone via PC or anything else?

Comment: Your question is poorly written.  It includes unclear terms such as "was is rooted".  -1.  Please [edit] it to improve the grammar and clarity, then ping me.

Comment: Thanks for editing.  Which version of KitKat are you running?  What have you tried already?  Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.  Each time you edit your question, it will get bumped to the top of the homepage; and more people might see it.

Comment: Please run Framaroot again.  What error message does it give you?  Please [edit] your question and tell us.

Comment: @Sridhar Are you using the latest framaroot version 1.9.3?

Comment: Same Error and I'm using V.1.9.3 only @Manubhargav unforgettableid

Comment: Have you done a Google search for [ `root Karbonn A51+` ] to find more information?  What advice did you find?  Did any of the advice work?  Please [edit] all this into your question.